What is the "closest approximation" to fields by an equational variety?
Consider the equational theory obtained by starting from the theory of commutative rings and adding a unary operator $(-)^{-1}$, the weak inverse, obeying the following equational axioms:

$a \cdot a^{-1} \cdot a = a$.
$(a^{-1})^{-1} = a$.
$(ab)^{-1} = a^{-1} b^{-1}$.
$0^{-1} = 0$. (Edit: As Chris Grossack observes, this quickly follows from axioms 1 and 2, whoops.)

Call a model of this theory a weak field. Every field $F$ is naturally a weak field in a unique way (compatible with its usual interpretation as a commutative ring): the operation $a^{-1}$ must send an element $a \in F$ to its ordinary inverse if $a \neq 0$ and to $0$ otherwise. But now we can take products, so e.g. all products of fields are weak fields, where $a^{-1}$ componentwise performs the above operation. Other examples include any ring satisfying $a^n = a$ for all $a$, where we can take the weak inverse to be $a^{-1} = a^{n-2}$. These are the subject of Jacobson's famous theorem that such rings are commutative. Every weak field is von Neumann regular.

Question: Do the above identities imply all identities true in all fields, regarded as weak fields? If we're missing some identities, what are they? Are they finitely axiomatizable?

Edit: I just saw the question What is the smallest variety of algebras containing all fields? in the sidebar, which is very closely related but I don't think it's exactly the same question (or if it is I don't see how and would appreciate an explanation), e.g. I am not making any assumptions about whether weak inverses are unique.

It sounds like you're asking about a generalization of fields, playfully called meadows in the literature. Precisely, a Meadow is a commutative ring with unit equipped with a (total!) unary ~bonus operation~ $(-)^{-1}$ so that

$x^2 x^{-1} = x$
$(x^{-1})^{-1} = x$

These are the same as your first two axioms. Since together these imply $0^{-2} \cdot 0 = 0^{-1}$, we get your axiom (4) for free. You can get (3) as well with a bit of work. See Proposition $2.8$ in Bergstra, Hirshfeld, and Tucker's Meadows and the Equational Specification of Division.
There's a fair amount that's been written about meadows (as you'll find on the linked website, dedicated entirely to raising awareness), but in particular you're likely to be interested in Bergstra, Hirshfeld, and Tucker's Meadows and the Equational Specification of Division. Quoting from that paper:

Our main task is to start to make a classification of meadows up to isomorphism. We prove the following general representation theorem:
Theorem. Up to isomorphism, the non-trivial meadows are precisely the subalgebras of products of zero totalized fields.
From this theorem we deduce this corollary:
Theorem. The equational theory of meadows and the equational theory of fields with zero totalized division are identical.
This strengthens a result for closed equations in [6]. Now we prove the following extension:
Theorem. The conditional equational theory of meadows and the conditional equational theory of fields with zero totalized division are identical.

Here, unsurprisingly, in case a meadow is called a zero totalized field exactly when it's a field with $0^{-1}$ defined to be $0$.
Also, [6] in that paper is Bergstra and Tucker's The rational numbers as an abstract datatype.

I hope this helps ^_^

Oh, thank you, I'd heard about meadows a long time ago but forgotten about them. Doesn't that 2nd theorem imply that axiom 3 should follow from the others, since axiom 3 holds in all fields?

I think it does imply that axiom (3) is provable, and I actually thought that while typing this up, but decided to not say it explicitly for fear of misunderstanding something, haha

Edit, 7/4: Okay, I actually had a look through Bergstra, Hirschfield, and Tucker and I was making things too complicated. I think the cleanest way to set things up is to alter the definition of the weak inverse slightly (replacing axiom 2 by a different axiom), namely:

Revised definition: A weak inverse $y$ of an element $x$ in a monoid is an element satisfying $xyx = x$ and $yxy = y$.

This is the definition used to define inverse semigroups, and setting $x = 0$ in a ring immediately gives $y = 0$, so axiom 4 follows. Now we can define a weak field to be a commutative ring which has all weak inverses (with respect to multiplication), and we have:

Proposition: In a commutative monoid, weak inverses are unique.

Proof. Suppose $x$ has two weak inverses $y, z$. By definition this gives $x^2 y = x = x^2 z$ and $x y^2 = y, x z^2 = z$. In particular we have $x^2 y^2 = xy$ and $x^2 z^2 = xz$. We can now compute that
$$y = xy^2 = (x^2 z) y^2 = (x^2 y^2) z = xyz = (xz) y = (x^2 z^2) y = (x^2 y) z^2 = xz^2 = z. \Box$$
This feels like something someone should've told me a long time ago!
In any case, uniqueness makes things much easier; now if $A$ is a weak field we check as before that it's reduced and that every quotient $A/P$ is a weak field, we show that an integral domain is a weak field (this is now a property!) iff it's a field, so every quotient $A/P$ is a field, and we embed $A$ into $\prod A/P$ which is a product of fields and hence a weak field, and this is automatically a morphism of weak fields by uniqueness.
We also get a direct proof of axiom 3:

Corollary: In a commutative monoid, the weak inverse satisfies $(xy)^{-1} = x^{-1} y^{-1}$.

Proof. We just need to verify that
$$xy (x^{-1} y^{-1}) xy = (x^2 x^{-1})(y^2 y^{-1}) = xy$$
and
$$(x^{-1} y^{-1}) xy (x^{-1} y^{-1}) = (x^{-2} x)(y^{-2} y) = x^{-1} y^{-1}$$
and then it follows by uniqueness. $\Box$

Deprecated answer: Okay, it's actually pretty straightforward. The answer is yes. This is probably standard material to some people but I want to go through it step-by-step to be sure. For clarity, the entire problem here is that we don't know a priori that weak inverses are unique.
For starters, axiom 1 gives $a = a^2 a^{-1}$, and if $a$ is nilpotent then repeatedly applying this identity (to get $a = (a^2 a^{-1})^2 a^{-1}$ etc.) gives that $a = 0$, so axiom 1 implies that weak fields are reduced. If $A$ is a weak field this means it embeds into a product of fields, namely
$$\varphi : A \hookrightarrow \prod_P \text{Frac}(A/P)$$
where the product runs over all prime ideals $P$. To prove our desired result it suffices to show that $\varphi$ is a morphism of weak fields, where $\prod_P \text{Frac}(A/P)$ has the pointwise weak field structure, since this would show that every equational statement in the language of weak fields true in all fields is true in all weak fields.
First we need a slight generalization of the observation above that fields have a unique weak field structure.

Lemma 1: An integral domain $D$ has a weak field structure in at most one way, iff it is a field, in which case $a^{-1}$ is either the ordinary inverse if $a \neq 0$ or is equal to $0$.

Proof. If $a \neq 0$ then $a$ can be cancelled from axiom 1 which gives that $a^{-1}$ is the usual inverse; in particular the usual inverse must exist, so $D$ must be a field. Axioms 1 and 2 imply $0^{-1} = 0$.  $\Box$

Lemma 2: If $A$ is a weak field and $P$ is a prime ideal of it (as a commutative ring), then the quotient map $\varphi_P : A \to A/P$ is a morphism of weak fields; in particular $A/P$ is a field and it has the unique weak field structure above.

Proof. Applying $\varphi_P$ to axiom 1 gives $\varphi(a)^2 \varphi(a^{-1}) = \varphi(a)$, hence that either $\varphi(a) = 0$ (so $a \in P$) or that $\varphi(a^{-1}) = \varphi(a)^{-1}$, where here this is the inverse in the usual sense (since $A/P$ is an integral domain). In particular $A/P$ is a field. This leaves open the possibility that we could have $\varphi(a) = 0$ but $\varphi(a^{-1}) \neq 0$. However, axiom 2 gives that if $\varphi(a^{-1}) \neq 0$ then $\varphi(a) = \varphi((a^{-1})^{-1}) = \varphi(a^{-1})^{-1}  \neq 0$. So in fact $\varphi(a^{-1})$ is uniquely determined by $\varphi(a)$ via the unique weak field structure on $A/P$, and $\varphi_P$ is a morphism of weak fields. $\Box$

Corollary: The canonical embedding $\varphi$ of $A$ into a product of fields has the form $\varphi : A \hookrightarrow \prod_P A/P$, and is a morphism of weak fields if the RHS is given the pointwise weak field structure. In particular, weak inverses are unique in weak fields.

So in fact axioms 1 and 2 suffice to prove all equational statements in the language of weak fields which are true in all fields, and in particular they imply axiom 3. The uniqueness of weak inverses also implies that the weak fields are exactly the commutative von Neumann regular rings, and that the category of weak fields embeds fully faithfully into commutative rings.
This discussion appears to imply something about commutative vNr rings that I do not think is at all obvious otherwise, which is that the inclusion of commutative vNr rings into commutative rings has a left adjoint! If it exists it is given by formally adjoining weak inverses and I have no idea what it looks like concretely. Does that sound right to anyone else?

The "weak fieldification" of $\mathbb{Z}$, which is also the initial object in the category of weak fields, appears to be $\mathbb{Z}[a_p]/(p^2 a_p = p, p a_p^2 = a_p)$. The elements $a_p$ are the weak inverses to the primes $p$ and they are quite bizarre, I've never thought about this before. They have the property that if you map them into a ring where $p = 0$ they are zero, but if you map them into a ring where $p$ is invertible they are $\frac{1}{p}$. In particular their image in any field is uniquely determined by the characteristic. How strange.
